# PHP Unit test case for AccessDeniedHttpException for code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, testcase, drupal-9

I m trying to write PHPUnit test case for code coverage for AccessDeniedHttpException class.

```
if($data['category'] != strip_tags($data['category'])) {
  $message="Html tags are not allowed in category. ";
  throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($message);
}
```

I tried couple of things

```
if($data['category'] != strip_tags($data['category'])) {
  $message="Html tags are not allowed in category. ";
  throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($message);
}
```

also

```
$this->expectException(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException::class);
throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();
```

Though the assertion passes but the coverage is not coming. I guess I am using wrong class in test case. Any suggestions?